# Read expiration date and common name from SSL certificate using Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

In an https-enabled Node.js I have the certificate as a `.pem` file.

Now I would like to read some data from that file to have information about the certificate, such as its expiration date and the common name.

As I have seen neither Node's very own [tls module](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html) nor modules such as [ursa](https://github.com/Obvious/ursa) support this.

Of course I might call `openssl` as a child process and parse its output stream (I think this task should be doable using OpenSSL), but I'd prefer a solution without relying on the availability of an external program in the path.

How could I do this?

**Update:** Meanwhile, I found the [pem module](https://github.com/andris9/pem), and its `readCertificateInfo` provides the common name successfully, even using Node.js 0.8.18 (which is contrary to its docs who state that 0.7+ is not supported). Unfortunately, it does not return the expiration date.

**Update 2:** Internally, pem just calls out for the `openssl` command using a child process. Of course I can do this by myself, hence I am able to retrieve the information required from `openssl` directly. Anyway, if someone has a better idea (which, in this case means, a pure JavaScript / Node.js solution) I'd be happy about it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the answer: The PEM format is basically ASN.1 using a Base64 encryption.

Hence, you need to Base64 decode first, and then parse the result as ASN.1. The result is the data structure of the certificate with the appropriate values in it.

That's it :-)!

Comment: Aware of a JS module that does this? Everything I've seen depends on OpenSSL being installed.

Comment: @Golo Roden: just a sidenote: base64 is an encoding (it can represent bytes as text), NOT an encryption (base64 provides no secrecy whatsoever).

Answer (score 3):

If you're obtaining the certificate from something like `tls.connect` you can call `getPeerCertificate()` and you'll get back a structure that looks like this (connected to github.com):

```
{ subject: 
   { C: 'US',
     ST: 'California',
     L: 'San Francisco',
     O: 'GitHub, Inc.',
     CN: '*.github.com' },
  issuer: 
   { C: 'US',
     O: 'DigiCert Inc',
     OU: 'www.digicert.com',
     CN: 'DigiCert High Assurance CA-3' },
  subjectaltname: 'DNS:*.github.com, DNS:github.com',
  modulus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
  exponent: '10001',
  valid_from: 'Apr 30 00:00:00 2012 GMT',
  valid_to: 'Jul  9 12:00:00 2014 GMT',
  fingerprint: 'B1:4B:A1:6F:5C:EE:28:DA:C4:86:CD:D9:F2:80:8F:2E:A7:4A:51:F4',
  ext_key_usage: [ '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1', '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2' ] }
```

I haven't found a decent way to parse arbitrary local certs though, sorry.

Comment: Basically correct, but I need it outside an actual connection :-(

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Node 11+ with the `tls` module via `getCertificate` (the local side analogue to `getPeerCertificate`):

```
import { TLSSocket } from "tls";

const socket = new TLSSocket(null, {
  cert: readFileSync(certFilePath)
});
const cert = socket.getCertificate();
socket.destroy();
```

cert:

```json
{
  subject: {
    CN: "localhost",
  },
  issuer: {
    CN: "localhost",
  },
  subjectaltname: "DNS:localhost",
  modulus: "C35160396...<truncated>",
  bits: 2048,
  exponent: "0x10001",
  pubkey: new Uint8Array([48, 130, /* truncated */]),
  valid_from: "Dec 10 20:27:22 2021 GMT",
  valid_to: "Dec 10 20:27:22 2022 GMT",
  fingerprint: "1E:04:BA:8E:01:C5:E9:1B:F9:A3:09:04:77:45:BB:C9:C4:A0:BB:D0",
  fingerprint256: "68:8F:97:70:AC:E2:52:AB:06:7B:F8:EA:2D:A5:6E:C7:DF:75:C4:D3:12:FB:E8:22:01:0A:71:5A:8D:05:6B:63",
  ext_key_usage: [
    "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1",
  ],
  serialNumber: "D02496A814147089",
  raw: new Uint8Array([48, 130, /* truncated */]),
}
```